# Add a subquery result to a query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to following subquery

```
    SELECT
    (
        SELECT SUM( `total_amount` )
        FROM `civicrm_contribution`
        WHERE `currency` = 'PCT'
        AND `contact_id` = ( SELECT `id`FROM `civicrm_contact`
        WHERE `first_name` = '' 
        UNION ALL
        SELECT `contact_id` FROM `civicrm_membership` 
        WHERE `source` = '')   
    )

-
(
    SELECT SUM(`fee_amount`)
    FROM `civicrm_participant`
    WHERE `fee_level`='puncte' 
    AND `contact_id` = (SELECT `id` FROM `civicrm_contact` 
    WHERE  `first_name` =''
    UNION ALL
    SELECT `contact_id` FROM `civicrm_membership` 
    WHERE `source` = '') 
)As RemainingPoints
```

and i don't know how to add the result to following queries

```
SELECT  `civicrm_contact`.first_name,`civicrm_membership`.start_date, `civicrm_membership`.end_date, `civicrm_membership`.source FROM `civicrm_contact`, `civicrm_membership` WHERE `civicrm_contact`.id = `civicrm_membership`.contact_id  AND `civicrm_membership`.source =''
UNION ALL    
SELECT  `civicrm_contact`.first_name,`civicrm_membership`.start_date, `civicrm_membership`.end_date, `civicrm_membership`.source FROM `civicrm_contact`, `civicrm_membership` WHERE `civicrm_contact`.id = `civicrm_membership`.contact_id  AND `civicrm_contact`.first_name ='test1'
```

I would like that the "RemainingPoints" to be added at the end of the query

first_name ;start_date;    end_date;  source;   "RemainingPoints"

Comment: For the future: Don't quote/backtick your column & table names.  They only add visual clutter and are just one more way for you to make syntax errors.  The only reason you need them is if you have a column name that is a reserved word, and using column names that are reserved words is a terrible idea, so that's two bad habits you can avoid at once.

Comment: @AndyLester Someone else posted that this often comes from copying queries from PhpMyAdmin, which adds the backticks automatically.

Comment: @Barmar: I understand that.  It's one of the reasons why I let people know that it's unnecessary and counterproductive.

Comment: How do you want to add it to the second query? You just want the same total to be on every row of the result?

Comment: @AndyLester But they can't really do anything about it, unless you expect them to go through it and remove all the backticks before pasting. We can't even get posters to indent their code properly!

Comment: @Barmar:I would like to be the same total on every row of the result

Comment: @Barmar: My point is not that it's not unnecessary here on SO, but that it's unnecessary in their own code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT `civicrm_contact`.first_name,`civicrm_membership`.start_date,  `civicrm_membership`.end_date, `civicrm_membership`.source FROM `civicrm_contact`, `civicrm_membership` WHERE `civicrm_contact`.id = `civicrm_membership`.contact_id  AND `civicrm_membership`.source =''
      UNION ALL    
      SELECT  `civicrm_contact`.first_name,`civicrm_membership`.start_date, `civicrm_membership`.end_date, `civicrm_membership`.source FROM `civicrm_contact`, `civicrm_membership` WHERE `civicrm_contact`.id = `civicrm_membership`.contact_id  AND `civicrm_contact`.first_name ='test1'
     ) x
JOIN (SELECT (
        SELECT SUM( `total_amount` )
        FROM `civicrm_contribution`
        WHERE `currency` = 'PCT'
        AND `contact_id` = ( SELECT `id`FROM `civicrm_contact`
        WHERE `first_name` = '' 
        UNION ALL
        SELECT `contact_id` FROM `civicrm_membership` 
        WHERE `source` = '')   
        )
        -
        (
        SELECT SUM(`fee_amount`)
        FROM `civicrm_participant`
        WHERE `fee_level`='puncte' 
        AND `contact_id` = (SELECT `id` FROM `civicrm_contact` 
        WHERE  `first_name` =''
        UNION ALL
        SELECT `contact_id` FROM `civicrm_membership` 
        WHERE `source` = '') 
        ) As RemainingPoints) y
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast answer, that save my day.The script is working perfect now.